# How to take another attribute value from another table, with known value from existing table

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a website where the system can generate patient bills based on clinic category and the action they've got in the clinic.

I have 3 tables :

1. Table to input the list of clinic category ("poli")
2. Table to input the list of clinic possible action for the patient ("tindakan")
3. Final table to input all of the above, where the patient choose one of the "poli" and the "tindakan" ("pasien").

This is some of my "poli" table entries :

```
    poli::create([
        'inisial' => 'GIGI',
        'namapoli' => 'Poli Gigi',
        'harga' => '12000',            
    ]);  

    poli::create([
        'inisial' => 'IMUN',
        'namapoli' => 'Poli Imun',
        'harga' => '10000',            
    ]);
```

This is some of my "tindakan" table entries :

```
    tindakan::create([         
        'namatindak' => 'Tindakan Medis Sederhana',
        'harga' => '10000',            
    ]); 

    tindakan::create([         
        'namatindak' => 'Tindakan Medis Ringan',
        'harga' => '15000',            
    ]); 

    tindakan::create([         
        'namatindak' => 'Tindakan Medis Sedang',
        'harga' => '30000',            
    ]);
```

This is my current input form for "pasien" :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Tambahkan Pasien</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Form untuk menambahkan pasien baru.</h6><br>
                <form method="post" action="/pasien" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="masuk">Tanggal</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="masuk" name="masuk" class="form-control @error('masuk') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Tanggal Perawatan">
                                    @error ('masuk')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        {{ $message }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="nama">Nama</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="nama" name="nama" class="form-control @error('nama') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
                                                @error ('nama')
                                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        {{ $message }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="poli">Poli</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="poli" id="role">                                                                                                           
                                                    @foreach ($poli as $info_poli)
                                                        <option value="{{ $info_poli->inisial }}">{{ $info_poli->inisial }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                                
                                                @error ('poli')
                                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        {{ $message }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="tindakan">Tindakan</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="tindakan" id="tindakan">
                                                    <option value="-">...</option>                                                       
                                                    @foreach ($tindakan as $info_tindakan)
                                                        <option value="{{ $info_tindakan->namatindak }}">{{ $info_tindakan->namatindak }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                                
                                                @error ('tindakan')
                                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        {{ $message }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <div class="text-right">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-dark">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my current table for "pasien" :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                <a href="/pasien/create" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Tambah Data</a><br>
                                <table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered no-wrap">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>No. Karcis</th>
                                            <th>Tanggal Masuk</th>
                                            <th>Nama</th>
                                            <th>Poli</th>
                                            <th>Harga Karcis</th> 
                                            <th>Tindakan</th> 
                                            <th>Harga Tindakan</th> 
                                            <th>Total</th> 
                                
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($pasien as $info_pasien)                                            
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>   
                                                               
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->id }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->masuk }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->nama }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->poli }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->poli }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->tindakan }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $info_pasien->tindakan }}</td>                                                
                                            <td>total</td>
      
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="/pasien/{{ $info_pasien->id }}/edit" class="badge bg-primary"><i data-feather="edit" style="color:white"></i></a>
                                                <form action="/pasien/{{ $info_pasien->id }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
                                                    @method('delete')
                                                    @csrf
                                                    <button class="badge bg-danger border-0" onclick="return confirm('Yakin hapus?')"><i data-feather="trash" style="color:white"></i></a>
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>No. Karcis</th>
                                            <th>Tanggal Masuk</th>
                                            <th>Nama</th>
                                            <th>Poli</th>
                                            <th>Harga Karcis</th> 
                                            <th>Tindakan</th> 
                                            <th>Harga Tindakan</th> 
                                            <th>Total</th> 
                                
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

This is my current "pasien" controller, I've tried calling the tables with "pasien" "id" but i don't know how to call them :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\pasien;

use App\Models\poli;
use App\Models\tindakan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class dashpasienController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('dashboard.pasien.index', [
            'pasien' => pasien::orderBy('id', 'desc')->latest()->get(),
            'sekarang' => Carbon::now(),
            
            'poli' => poli::orderBy('id', 'desc')->latest()->get(),
            'tindakan' => tindakan::orderBy('id', 'desc')->latest()->get(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view ('dashboard.pasien.create', [
            
            'poli' => poli::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->get(),
            'tindakan' => tindakan::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->get(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {                    
        $validateData = $request->validate([
            
            'masuk' => 'required',
            'nama' => 'required',
            'poli' => 'required',
            'tindakan' => 'required',          
        ]);

      
                          
        pasien::create($validateData);

        return redirect('/pasien')->with('success','Data pasien berhasil ditambahkan');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\pasien  $pasien
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(pasien $pasien)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\pasien  $pasien
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('dashboard.pasien.edit',[
            
            'poli' => poli::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->get(),
            'tindakan' => tindakan::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->get(),
        ])->with(['pasien' => pasien::findOrFail($id)]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\pasien  $pasien
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        
        $validateData = $request->validate([
           
            'masuk' => 'required',
            'nama' => 'required',
            'poli' => 'required',
            'tindakan' => 'required', 
        ]);
        
        pasien::where('id', $id)->update($validateData);

        return redirect('/pasien')->with('success','Data pasien berhasil diperbarui');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\pasien  $pasien
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        pasien::destroy($id);

        return redirect('/pasien')->with('success','Data pasien berhasil dihapus');
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get "poli->harga" from "poli" table and "tindakan->harga" from "tindakan" table to the current "harga poli" and "harga tindakan" column in "pasien" database. I also uploaded some picture to illustrate what I'm trying to do (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Have you defined the relationships between your models? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships